# How would I take a user-input number and work on its digits individually?

Tags: java

I'm prompting a user for a number and am trying to determine the amount of even, odd, and zeros in that number

```
/* This program will determine and print the number of even, zero, and odd digits in 
 * an integer
 * 
 * Author: Marco Monreal
 * Date: 11/01/2016
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PP5_3
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String exit_loop, go_again, user_num, first_char_string;
    int odds, evens, zeros;
    int first_char; //, second_char, third_char, fourth_char, fifth_char, sixth_char, seventh_char, eighth_char, ninth_char, tenth_char;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    evens = 0;
    odds = 0;
    zeros = 0;
    exit_loop = "no"; //initializing while loop

    while (exit_loop.equals ("no"))
    {

      System.out.println ("Choose any number between 0 and 2,147,483,647. Don't include commas please.");
      user_num = scan.next ();
```

I'm getting stuck around this area; "first_char" is not returning the digit value that I want/need.

```
      //assigning a variable to each character of user_num
      first_char = user_num.lastIndexOf(0);
      /*second_char = user_num.charAt(1);
      third_char = user_num.charAt(2);
      fourth_char = user_num.charAt(3);
      fifth_char = user_num.charAt(4);
      sixth_char = user_num.charAt(5);
      seventh_char = user_num.charAt(6);
      eighth_char = user_num.charAt(7);
      ninth_char = user_num.charAt(8);
      tenth_char = user_num.charAt(9);*/

      //copy every character into a string value
      first_char_string = String.valueOf(first_char);


      if (first_char == 2 || first_char == 4 || first_char == 6 || first_char == 8)
      {
        evens++;
      }

      else if (first_char_string.equals("1") || first_char_string.equals("3") || first_char_string.equals("5") || first_char_string.equals("7") ||
               first_char_string.equals("9"))
      {
        odds++;
      }

      else
        zeros++;

    } //ends while loop

    System.out.println ("There are " +evens+ " even numbers, " +odds+ " odd numbers, and " +zeros+ "zeros in ");

    scan.close ();
  } //ends main method
} //ends class
```

Comment: JavaScript is not Java... at least other questions have both tags, this one _only_ mentions JavaScript by supplying Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi take a look on this line:

```
user_num = scan.next (); // this will scan your user input, but does not jump to the next line
```

you might want to use:

```
user_num = scan.nextLine();
```

Also you made a mistake in your `lastIndexOf(char)` method.
This method expects a char. you supply this method an int e.g:

```
first_char = user_num.lastIndexOf(0);
```

this works because java interprets your number a an ASCI-number. the char representated by ASCI "0" is null. What you want to do is search for the character '0'. Like the following:

```
first_char = user_num.lastIndexOf('0');
```

The same for your equalisations:

```
first_char == 2 ---> first_char == '2';
```

Another notice. Please use camel case istead of underscores. instead of user_num you should write userNum. Thats the standard.

Yet another notice. The `lastIndexOf()` method will return the nummber of the last occurence of the parameter. e.g:

```
String  test = "hello test";
test.lastIndexOf(e); // this will return 7 for it is the number ofthe last occurence of 'e'
```

I think yu want to use `charAt(0)` this returns the charactere at specified position

Last Notice. why are you comparing char values representing numbers ?
why not do the following:

int userNum = Integer.valueOf(yourCharHere).

**Update**

If I understood your comment correctly the your 'X' in the snippet below is defined by the user

first_char = userNum.charAt(X);

If I get you right you have a problem because you dont know how long the input of the user is. Instead of assigning the individual numers to variables I would do the following:

//Parsing your String into a int
    int userNum = Integer.valueOf(yourUserInputHere);
    Arraylist singleDigits = new ArrayList()<>;

```
//This goes through all digits of your number starting with the last digits
while (userNum > 0) {
    singleDigits.add( userNum % 10);
    userNum = userNum / 10;
}
```

//Reverses your list of digits
   Collections.reverse(singleDigits);

Example input: `13467`
your List should look like: `[1],[3],[4],[6],[7]`

This enables you to get the single digits by calling:

```
singleDigits.get(0) -> [1];
singleDigits.get(3) -> [6];
...
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Hey Tom thanks for your advice! I'm still a little confused though. I will not be choosing what integer "userNum" gets, that'll be up to the user which is why this makes it a little tricky for me. I will not know what digit is in what place (char value), so I was hoping to find a way to pull that out of the "userNum" that the user chooses. Sorry if I can't explain it very well, i'm just confused.

Comment: @Tom Wellbrock That symbol _ is called an underscore ;)

Answer (score 0):

First create sets that are containing odd/even/zero numbers:

```
Set<Integer> odds = "13579".chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<Integer> evens = "02468".chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<Integer> zero = "0".chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Then get an input from the user

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Choose a number:");
String number = scan.next();
scan.close();
```

Parse `number` character by character to find out how many digits are matching each set:

```
long numberOfOdds = number.chars().filter(odds::contains).count();
long numberOfEvens = number.chars().filter(evens::contains).count();
long numberOfZeros = number.chars().filter(zero::contains).count();
```

Finally, display the result:

```
System.out.println("There are " + numberOfEvens + " even numbers, " + numberOfOdds + " odd numbers, and " + numberOfZeros + " zeros in ");
```